# Matrix algebra question about square matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm having a lot of trouble with the following question from Coursera:

Let A and B be n-by-n matrices with $(AB)_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik} b_{kj}$

If A and B are upper triangular matrix, then $a_{ik}=0$ or $b_{kj}=0$ when:

A:k<i

B:k>i

C:k<j

D:k>j

This question seems quite abstract to me and I don't know where to start or what to do, I know that a and b are the components of the A and B matrices and that i and j are the rows and columns respectively, I don't actually know what the k index represents though. Like how do I "calculate" k to know whether if j and i need to be greater or lower than it in order for b or a to be zero.

Comment: So $a_{ik} $ is the entry of matrix $A$ in the $(i, k )$ position. If $k >i $ then $a_{ik} $ is the entry in the $(i, k) $ position which is below the main diagonal.

Comment: Strange question. The product $AB$ is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Upper triangular matrix means: all entries below the diagonal are $0$ ( so "all" is concentrated above the diagonal). Now, position $(i,j)$ ($i$ for row, $j$ for column ) is below the diagonal means $i> j$. Therefore:

$A$ upper triangular matrix means $a_{ij}=0$ whenever $i>j$.

I guess part of the problem is showing that if $A$, $B$ are upper triangular, then so is $AB$.  Now
$$(AB)_{ij} = \sum_k a_{ik} \cdot b_{kj}$$

Say we look at a position below the diagonal, that is $i>j$. Then, for every $k$, at least one of the inequalities $i>k$, or $k>j$ is true ( otherwise, if both $i\le k$, and $k\le j$, then by transitivity you would get $i\le j$, not true). Now, since for every $k$, at least one of $i>k$, or $j>k$ is true, it means that at least one of $a_{ik}$, $b_{kj}=0$, so their product $a_{ik} \cdot b_{kj}=0$. Therefore, in the sum $\sum_k a_{ik} \cdot b_{kj}$ each summand is $0$, so the sum is also $0$. We conclude:

if $i>j$ then $(AB)_{ij}=0$. Therefore $AB$ is also upper triangular.